# append method in python not working as expected in nested for loops

Tags: python, list, loops, append, nested-loops

I want to append a list into another list using nested for loops but the code is not working as expected

```
def apend():
    ls = []
    numbers = [0,0]
    
    for num1 in range(3):
        for num2 in range(2):
            numbers[0] = num1
            numbers[1] = num2
            ls.append(numbers)
    print(ls)

apend()
```

I expect the output to be: `[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]`

but i get this output: `[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]`

Comment: I think it's related to https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures . Maybe try to instantiate the `numbers` in your inner for loop.

Comment: You are appending a reference to the same list in each iteration. Just append `[num1, num2]` instead.

Comment: can someone explain me please why this is not working

Comment: `ls` keeps it as reference to the same `numbers` but you should create new `number` before you put it in `ls`. OR do `ls.append([num1, num2])` BTW: run your code on http://pythontutor.com/ and you will see references as arrows on visualization - and all arrows with refere to the same list `number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your code on http://pythontutor.com/ then you see

[image]

All elements in list `ls` keep reference to the same list `numbers` and this makes problem.

You have to create new list `numbers = [0,0]` inside `for`-loop

```
for num1 in range(3):
    for num2 in range(2):
        numbers = [0,0]
        numbers[0] = num1
        numbers[1] = num2
        ls.append(numbers)
```

Or simply do it without `numbers`

```
for num1 in range(3):
    for num2 in range(2):
        ls.append([num1, num2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the numbers to numbers[:] and you will get you output as expected.

`ls.append(numbers)` means you are appending the reference of the list .
so when the list changes , all instace changes .
when you do `ls.append(numbers[:])`  this appends a copy of numbers.

```
def apend():
    ls = []
    numbers = [0,0]
    
    for num1 in range(3):
        for num2 in range(2):
            numbers[0] = num1
            numbers[1] = num2
            ls.append(numbers[:])
    print(ls)

apend()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the list named numbers in the loop.
Just append a new list object as below.

```
def apend():
    ls = []
    numbers = [0,0]
    
    for num1 in range(3):
        for num2 in range(2):
            numbers[0] = num1
            numbers[1] = num2
            ls.append(list(numbers)) # append a new list object 
    print(ls)
```

By the way, I'd like to use list comprehension for this function.

```
def append():
    ls = [[x, y] for x in range(3) for y in range(2)]
    print(ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it it in this way :

```
def apend():
    ls=[]
    numbers=[0,0]
    for num1 in range(3):
        for num2 in range(2):
            numbers[0]=num1
            numbers[1]=num2
            ls.append(num.copy())
    print(ls)
apend()
```